# Can not change cell size in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

I create tableViewController and need to make the last cell bigger. But I can't to set the size as I want. Here My code

```
cell.bounds = CGRectMake(0,45,320,900);
        [[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row]removeFromSuperview] ;
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 400, 500);
        CGRect frame2 = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 500);
        [cell setFrame:frame];
        [cell setBounds:frame2];

        //[self tableView].rowHeight = 500;
        UITextView *txtView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        txtView.text = @"SEND FROM MY IPAD";
        txtView.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:txtView];
        [txtView release];
```

But I can change  height for some pixels and all([image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement UITableViewDelegate Protocol in order to change row (cell) height. See method [tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForRowAtIndexPath%3a).

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 100.0f;
}
```

To change width just set UITableView's width to required value.